# font is missing when download in Highcharts

Tags: php, graph, fonts, highcharts, webfonts

I'm using [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/) script for displaying chart. And Im using Burmese(myanmar language) font.

Font is coming correctly, when graph is loading. But when I'm downloading as PNG and so, Font Family is not support.

What to do?

I'm using PHP and MySQL.

My Screen Shot:

[image]

While Download:

[image]

Comment: If you have your own export server setup the server also needs to have the fonts.

Comment: What do you mean with "when downloading as PNG"? Either it's already a PNG on the website, in which case the bits don't change and the image stays the same, or it's not, in which case you're not downloading a PNG, you're doing something else: can you describe the steps you are performing? Also, notice that the screenshot you're showing is *also* broken, there are some "empty box" symbols mixed in with the Burmese.

Comment: Please ensure if you website / html file and meta tags are encoded as utf8

Comment: @SebastianBochan no use...

Comment: As I know Burmese font is not supported on Highcharts exporting server. I see two options: 1) Setup your own exporting server and install necessary fonts. 2) Contact with Highcharts team  (via e-mail) and ask for that font on the server.